# Is setting formUriBasicAuthPassword and other sensitive data in ACRA as plain text secure (enough)?

Tags: android, security, acra

I'm trying to establish ACRA connection with Acralyzer. All credentials are set properly in @ReportsCrashes annotation and it works fine.
I'm wondering, **is it secure to set Acralyzer link, login, and password as plain text?** I'm afraid that by using reveresed engineering I can lose control of my Acralyzer account.
My config looks something like this:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "https://some_link_to_acralyzer",
            httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.PUT,
            reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
            formUriBasicAuthLogin = "some_login",
            formUriBasicAuthPassword = "some_password"
```

Should I encrypt this data myself before introducing into the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I encrypt this data myself before introducing into the code?

No, the login won't work if you encrypt this data.

> I'm afraid that by using reveresed engineering I can lose control of my Acralyzer account

That is why you shouldn't put your admin credentials in the configuration, but instead create a separate `Reporter` user.

Comment: I do have a separate Reporter user, but using this credentials someone can spoof my data or even worse. I also realize that sending encrypted password wouldn't work, but I could use a decrypting method just before setting it into configuration. I'm only concerned that would do nothing because one can check the password value jest before sending.

Comment: The more common way to spy on passwords is intercepting the request. What happens inside the java code is not the important part. NB: While I am using Acralyzer myself It might be a good idea to use another backend. Acralyzer has some minor issues and is not under active development.

Comment: What are those issues you are talking about? Can you recommend any other backend software?

Comment: E.g. I wanted to assign a user to only have access to one app, while not seeing the others. That was not possible (write access could be restricted, but not read). As I said I am still using it, because I started with it and migrating is kinda annoying. So, I can't recommend anything else. But the list is long https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends

Comment: Thanks for the response!